# Relaunch a python script stopped by a CTRL+Z and containing a Fortran executable launched by os.system

Tags: bash, shell, jobs

I was running a Python script which launches several times a Fortran executable (with `os.system('./executable params.ini)`.

Unfortunately, I did a CTRL+Z to stop the python script but it seems that I have stopped it during the execution of the Fortran executable.

Now, impossible to relaunch the Python script. I tried. :

```
fg %1
```

and

```
bg %1
```

and

```
kill -CONT pid_of_executable
```

But nothing happens ...

So, is there a way to relaunch the python script ? I am frustrated ... if anyone could save my life ... (I am joking)

**UPDATE 1:** Once Python script stopped by CTRL+Z, `pa aux | grep compute` 
 gives :

```
user1              38258   0.0  0.0  6121988  10324 s003  S     3:26PM   0:00.99 /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python compute_Cl_variable_step_160_between_1e-8_and_1_values_Only_Omega_m_der_to_choose.py
user1              33564   0.0  0.0  6010372  16472 s012  S+    1:34PM   0:01.44 /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python compute_Cl_variable_step_160_between_1e-8_and_1_values_Only_Omega_m_der_to_choose.py
user1              96299   0.0  0.0  6509060  12668 s004  S+    6:06PM   0:01.77 /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python compute_Cl_variable_step_160_between_1e-8_and_1_values_Only_Omega_m_der_to_choose.py
```

Comment: yes I can see it (with `compute` substring of python script name) : `ps aux | grep compute` gives :

Comment: `user1              38258   0.0  0.0  6121988  10324 s003  S     3:26PM   0:00.99 /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python compute_Cl_variable_step_160_between_1e-8_and_1_values_Only_Omega_m_der_to_choose.py
user1              33564   0.0  0.0  6010372  16472 s012  S+    1:34PM   0:01.44 /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python compute_Cl_variable_step_160_between_1e-8_and_1_values_Only_Omega_m_der_to_choose.py`

Comment: `user1              96299   0.0  0.0  6509060  12668 s004  S+    6:06PM   0:01.77 /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python compute_Cl_variable_step_160_between_1e-8_and_1_values_Only_Omega_m_der_to_choose.py`

Comment: @oguzismail Do you think it is dead for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
jobs
```

you can see the suspended jobs

```
fg jobnummer
```

will bring it back.